# Unable to open python files in python.exe of python 2.7

Tags: file, python-2.7, open-with

I have installed python 2.7 but could not open python files.
I can see C:\Python27\python.exe, even in command prompt I can see Python2.7 is installed. When I try to open python file with right click -> open with, it is showing only microsoft visual studio and pythonw.exe. I am not able to see python.exe in that list.

Am I missing any settings here?

Comment: You may need to reboot the computer for windows explorer to re-index the application launcher folder.  If still not working, then in the "Open with..." dialog, just browser to your python.exe.  Alternatively and arguably better, make sure your python installation folder is on the system `Path` variable, and then in a command prompt, browse to your python file and run `python <yourfilename>`.  This will let you run it multiple times in succession and actually see any output that occurs.

Comment: when I am trying to open python file ,by default it is opening in visual studio

Comment: I tried python <yourfilename>,but not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you shuld go on Command Prompt and get in the directory of the python script and digit:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe <filename.py>
```

Comment: my python scripts are not recognized as python files ,

Comment: when I save the file as filename.py , i can not see the file with python icon